# Memory leak generating thumbnail

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, memory-leaks

When I use the code below I am experiencing a memory leak. Each time I run the code the memory consumption of the application goes up. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing with this code that causes it to keep increasing in memory consumption whenever that controller method is called?

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(pageService.getBaseLocation() + File.separator + page.getSha1()));
if(originalImage != null){
    int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
        int width = new Double(originalImage.getWidth() * (300.0/originalImage.getHeight())).intValue();
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width,300, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, 300, null);
        g.dispose();    






        ImageIO.write(resizedImage,"png",response.getOutputStream());


        response.flushBuffer();

        response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

Comment: how are you measuring memory used in the application?  also does it ever run out of memory?

Comment: how do you know that memory is not freed after GC cycle?

Comment: Just using task manager from windows and monitoring the java Process. It jumps 300MB or so the first time then 100MB every subsequent run calling the method with the same data. Each time I call my controller method this code snippet gets called about 200 times.

Comment: michal rybak how can i check?

Comment: You can use a tool like jvisualvm, which comes packaged with the jdk for free.  I would keep calling the controller logic to see if the program runs out of memory or not.

Comment: thanks for the tip ill check that out. I keep calling the controller method and it seems to top out just under 2gb, its still an extra gb than what my app was running on before i called this method which is concerning, and i lied it continues to go up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so using the task manager was a dumb way to really check this. Using springinsight I see that my memory consumption is not rising. Sorry for the trouble.